# Sequent database access with swift, vapor and fluent

Tags: swift, concurrency, orm, fluent, vapor

I am experimenting with some Server-Side-Swift tutorial. I have the two tables:

```
   acronyms(id: uuid, short: text, long: text, userID: uuid)
   users(id: uuid, name: text, username: text)
```

The following is working fine, a can insert new records in the acronyms-table via post-request:

```
import Vapor
import Fluent

struct AcronymsController: RouteCollection{

    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        let acronymsRoutes = routes.grouped("api", "acronyms")
    //  acronymsRoutes.get(use: getAllHandler)
        acronymsRoutes.post(use: createHandler)
    }

    func createHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Acronym> {
            let formData = try req.content.decode(FormData.self)

            let acronym = Acronym(id: formData.id,
                                  short: formData.short,
                                  long: formData.long,
                                  userID: formData.userID
            )

            return acronym.save(on: req.db).map { acronym }

        }
}

struct FormData: Content{
    let id: UUID
    let short: String
    let long: String
    let userID: UUID
}
```

Now I would like to use the username (unique) to run a query for user.id against the user table and use the result to insert a new acronym record (see below).

I understand, that I cannot call the asyncronous function `getUserIDByName` from within a sync function. So how is that to be done right?

Or, probably much faster, how can I directly send the following (p)sql-statement:

```
insert into acronyms values (
   '5bfc01d6-1b6a-45f0-86d7-5833a9c59fcd', 
   'bawdsf', 'bier auf wein, das schmeckt fein', 
   (select id from users where username like 'otto')
);
```

Many thanks in advance.

Michael

```
...
        func createHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Acronym> {
            let formData = try req.content.decode(FormData.self)

            let uid: UUID = try await getUserIDByName(req, username: formData.username)

            let acronym = Acronym(id: formData.id,
                                  short: formData.short,
                                  long: formData.long,
                                  userID: uid
            )

            return acronym.save(on: req.db).map { acronym }

    }
}

struct FormData: Content{
    let id: UUID
    let short: String
    let long: String
    let username: String
}


func getUserIDByName(_ req: Request, username: String )  async throws -> UUID {
    return
      try await
      User.query(on: req.db)
      .filter(\.$username == username)
      .first()
      .get()!.id!
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your `getUserIDByName` function to do this, just make it return a Future.

```swift
func getUserIDByName(_ req: Request, username: String ) -> EventLoopFuture<User?> {
    return
      User.query(on: req.db)
      .filter(\.$username == username)
      .first()
}
```

Then, `flatMap` this value and use it in your original route, modified:

```swift
func createHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Acronym> {
    return getUserIDByName(req, username:"otto").flatMap { user in
        guard let user = user, let userID = user.id else { throw SomeError() }
 
        let formData = try req.content.decode(FormData.self)

        let acronym = Acronym(id: formData.id,
                              short: formData.short,
                              long: formData.long,
                              userID: userID)

        return acronym.save(on: req.db).flatMap { acronym }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, make it all async:

```swift
func getUserIDByName(_ req: Request, username: String )  async throws -> User {
    return
      try await
      User.query(on: req.db)
      .filter(\.$username == username)
      .first()
}
```

And then:

```swift
func createHandler(_ req: Request) async throws -> Acronym {
    let formData = try req.content.decode(FormData.self)

    guard let uid = try await getUserIDByName(req, username: formData.username).id
    else { throw SomeError() }

    let acronym = Acronym(id: formData.id,
                          short: formData.short,
                          long: formData.long,
                          userID: uid)

    try await acronym.save(on: req.db)
    return acronym
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I tested both examples and got the all-async-example to work. 

User.query(on: req.db) returns an optional type, so I first tried to force-unwrap the value.

This is a quick but poor solution, because the program crashes when you pass a user that is not in the database.

I come from java and still have a lot to learn about concurrency and optional types.

Comment: @michaD, I have edited my answer to correct my oversight!

Comment: Hi Nick, I am a stackoverflow newbie and had to figure out how to accept a reply first. Thanks again and many greetings from southern Germany.